# Uploading to dynamic end-point with dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am looking to use [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), by means of [vue2-dropzone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-dropzone), and have a need to be able to upload to a dynamic endpoint, though I am not sure how to go about this.

The intended flow is:

- send filename and content-type to server and have returned the upload url
- upload the file to the url returned in the previous step

I did see in the options there was a `url` option that can take a function that can return a URL, but this does not seem well adapted to my needs. The limitation is that it is a synchronous operation, while any query to a server would be an asynchronous operations, unable to return the response on `return`.

Can anyone indicate whether this is doable with dropzone.js?

BTW the server is essentially creating a signed AWS S3 URL via `s3.getSignedUrl()` of the AWS SDK and also adding extra metadata.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the dropzone events

```
<vue-dropzone ref="vueDropzone" id="dropzone" :options="dropzoneOptions" @vdropzone-processing="dropzoneChangeUrl"></vue-dropzone>
```

And in your vue

```
data() {
        return {
            dynamicId: 123,
            dropzoneOptions: {
                url: 'url',
                thumbnailWidth: 150,
                maxFilesize: 0.5,
                uploadMultiple: true
            }
        }
    },
methods: {
    dropzoneChangeUrl() {
            this.$refs.vueDropzone.setOption('url', `http://your-url.com/${this.dynamicId}`);
        },
}
```

If you want to add some headers to the request or add parameters in the formData you can do that with the `vdropzone-sending(file, xhr, formData)` event. Here is an example

```
<vue-dropzone ref="vueDropzone" id="dropzone" :options="dropzoneOptions" @vdropzone-sending="sendImages"></vue-dropzone>
```

In your vue

```
sendImages(file, xhr, formData) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Header', 'Your Header');
    formData.append('photos', file);
}
```

Where file is the file your are sending (if you have multiple files, it will do the function for each one of them), xhr is the XMLHttpRequest, and the formData is the FormData.

Answer (score 1):

This should be doable.

One option I see is to use the `sending` event and modify the url on the xhr object.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending